# Cannot set background color of div

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Document Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="border:1px solid black;"
           style="background-color: green !important;">
        Test Text
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The border exists as specified.  However, the background of the div is not green.  Why is the background of the div not green?

I know this is basic, but I've been reading for hours and I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Use style="border:1px solid black; background-color: green;" instead of the two separate style attributes.

Comment: While the answers correct your problem (multiple style attributes), I would suggest you separate out your CSS either into a `<style></style>` or an entirely different file. Inline CSS is generally best to avoid as it's a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one style attribute per element so the second one is being ignored. Just combine them:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;background-color: green !important;">
    Test Text
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k1jta9vL/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use one style attribute. Also, you don't need `!important`, inline styles always have highest priority.

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black; background-color: green;">
  Test Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use only one style in your codding to achieve property of CSS.

here the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Document Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="border:1px solid black;background-color: green;">
        Test Text
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```